# How to standardize field values on create or write in Odoo 8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In Odoo 8, is there a preferred method for standardizing field values on create or write? Several methods come to mind, but this functionality seems like it belongs in the API. Essentially, I am wanting to create a field that specifies a standardize function, somewhat like a compute field that only specifies an inverse function. Does this already exist somewhere in the API?

**Method 0: Create a field that specifies a standardize function.**

The only flaw that I can see with this method is that the API does not exist.

```python
import openerp

class Model(openerp.models.Model):

  _name = 'addon.model'

  field = openerp.fields.Text(
    required=True,
    standardize='_standardize_field',
  )

  @openerp.api.one
  def _standardize_field(self):
    self.field = self.field.upper()
```

**Method 1: Override the create and write methods to insert a call to standardize the field.**

This works, but seems rather verbose for what could be done with a single function, above. Note that the constraint is required if `required=True` and the standardization might yield an empty field.

```python
import openerp

class Model(openerp.models.Model):

  _name = 'addon.model'

  field = openerp.fields.Text(
    required=True,
  )

  @openerp.api.one
  @openerp.api.constrains('field')
  def _constrains_field(self):
    if len(self.field) == 0:
      raise openerp.exceptions.ValidationError('Field must be valid.')

  def _standardize(self, args):
    if 'field' in args:
      # Return standardized field or empty string.
      args['field'] = args['field'].upper()

  @openerp.api.model
  def create(self, args):
    self._standardize(args)
    return super(Model, self).create(args)

  @openerp.api.multi
  def write(self, args):
    self._standardize(args)
    super(Model, self).write(args)
    return True
```

**Method 2: Use a computed field and a bit of magic.**

This works but feels a bit contrived. In addition, this method requires that the standardization function is deterministic, or this may create an infinite loop. Note that the standardization function may be called twice, which could be a concern if standardization is an expensive operation.

```python
import openerp

class Model(openerp.models.Model):

  _name = 'addon.model'

  field = openerp.fields.Text(
    compute=lambda x: x,
    inverse='_inverse_field',
    required=True,
    store=True,
  )

  @openerp.api.one
  @openerp.api.constrains('field')
  def _constrains_field(self):
    if self._standardize_field() is None:
      raise openerp.exceptions.ValidationError('Field must be valid.')

  def _inverse_field(self):
    field = self._standardize_field()

    # If the field is updated during standardization, this function will
    # run a second time, so use this check to prevent an infinite loop.
    if self.field != field:
      self.field = field

  def _standardize_field(self):
    # Return the standardized field.
    return self.field.upper()
```

**Method 3: Use a regular field and a computed field, with only the computed field being exposed in the view.**

The readonly flag and the constraints help to protect the underlying field, but I am not certain that this method would maintain data integrity, and the method as a whole feels contrived.

```python
import openerp

class Model(openerp.models.Model):

  _name = 'addon.model'

  field = openerp.fields.Text(
    readonly=True,
    required=True,
  )

  field_for_view = openerp.fields.Text(
    compute='_compute_field_for_view',
    inverse='_inverse_field_for_view',
    required=True,
  )

  @openerp.api.one
  @openerp.api.depends('field')
  def _compute_field_for_view(self):
    self.field_for_view = self.field

  @openerp.api.one
  @openerp.api.constrains('field', 'field_for_view')
  def _constrains_field(self):
    if self._standardize_field() is None:
      raise openerp.exceptions.ValidationError('Field must be valid.')

  def _inverse_field(self):
    self.field = self._standardize_field()

  def _standardize_field(self):
    # Return the standardized field.
    return self.field_for_view.upper()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the 'default' attribute is an implementation of your approach #1?
Here's the example taken from the Odoo8 documentation at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/orm.html#creating-models

```
a_field = fields.Char(default=compute_default_value)

def compute_default_value(self):
    return self.get_value()
```

Another option is to override the `write()` method in your subclass to add your call like so:

```
    def write(self, vals):

        for record in self:
            # do the cleanup here for each record, storing the result in 
            # vals again

        # call the super:
        res = super(extendedProject, self).write(vals)

        return res
```

`vals` is a dictionary with the modified values to store; `self` is a recordset with all records to store the values to. Note that the transaction in Odoo may still be rolled back after returning from your call to `write`.

Comment: When a field does not have a value, for example, when creating a new record, the default attribute proposes a value for that field. The value can then be modified, and may or may not be saved. In contrast, I am wanting to standardize the value of a field whenever it is saved. For example, when a mailing address is entered, I could standardize and validate the address when saving the record. In my case, I want to allow a user to enter HTML without requiring their HTML to be perfect, so I clean up the HTML when the record is saved, using method 1 above.

Comment: Ah, ok. you could then also just override the `write` method and do any cleanup then. I'll update the answer to add that option.

Comment: Did you see method 1 in the question? I note there that several additional steps are required if overriding the `write()` method, as one also needs to override the `create()` method and sometimes also needs to use the `@constrains` decorator.

Comment: Oops, ok, then you have my answer already in your question. I agree is rather verbose for a simple thing, but I don't know a better way.

Comment: Exactly. I am hoping to implement standardization more succinctly. Probably the ideal approach would be to patch the Odoo core to add a `standardize` attribute to the API. But overriding create() and write() works too.